# Как в javaFX обновить Label из второго потока

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь написать таймер обратного отсчета времени. В Label lbTimerCountDown должен отображаться текущее состояние времени в виде минуты:секунды "mm:ss" . Таймер запускаю во втором потоке и зависает основной поток пока не остановится второй. Вот реализация:

Main

```
public class Main extends Application {

     public static Controller controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{


    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    controller = loader.getController();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Таймер");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Основной поток

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {

@FXML
private TextField tfMinute;

@FXML
private Label lbTimerCountDown;

@FXML
private Button btnStartCountDown;

public Label getLbTimerCountDown() {
    return lbTimerCountDown;
}

public void initialize(){

    btnStartCountDown.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ANY, actionEventHandler);
}


private EventHandler<Event> actionEventHandler = new EventHandler<Event>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {

        if (event.getSource() == btnStartCountDown) {

            CountDown countDown = new CountDown();
            countDown.start();

        }

    }};
}
```

второй поток

```
import javafx.application.Platform;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class CountDown extends Thread {


private LocalTime timerCountDown;
private DateTimeFormatter dtfLocalTime;
private DateTimeFormatter dtfLocalTimeMinuteSecund;


@Override
public void run() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                dtfLocalTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
                dtfLocalTimeMinuteSecund = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss");

                while (!Main.controller.getLbTimerCountDown().getText().equals("00:00")) {

                    timerCountDown = LocalTime.parse("00:" + Main.controller.getLbTimerCountDown().getText(), dtfLocalTime);
                    timerCountDown = timerCountDown.minusSeconds(1);
                    Main.controller.getLbTimerCountDown().setText(timerCountDown.format(dtfLocalTimeMinuteSecund));

                    System.out.println(timerCountDown.format(dtfLocalTimeMinuteSecund));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

        }
    }); 
}
}
```

насчет Platform.runLater(new Runnable()) я не уверен нужен ли? с ним или без него основной поток висит одинаково.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильно реализованной команде   Platform.runLater(() ->
немного поправив код заработал как задумывалось... возможно я не правильно решил проблему, буду рад если подскажите реализацию задачи иначе.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    dtfLocalTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    dtfLocalTimeMinuteSecund = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss");

    while (!Main.controller.getLbTimerCountDown().getText().equals("00:00")) {

        try {
            timerCountDown = LocalTime.parse("00:" + Main.controller.getLbTimerCountDown().getText(), dtfLocalTime);
            timerCountDown = timerCountDown.minusSeconds(1);

            Platform.runLater(() -> Main.controller.getLbTimerCountDown().setText(timerCountDown.format(dtfLocalTimeMinuteSecund)));
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("timer end");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX, как и многие другие GUI-библиотеки, однопоточна. Вы не должны пытаться из главного потока или любого другого потока взаимодействовать с элементами графического интерфейса - это приведёт к сбою. Вы не должны внутри обработчиков событий запускать потоки - это приведёт к сбою. И вы не должны останавливать поток - это приведёт к сбою.

`Platform.runLater()` не предназначен для продолжительных задач, его стоит использовать только для разового изменения UI. Например, он подойдёт для вызова из потока, который получает текст по ссылке, устанавливает этот текст в поле и завершает работу. Для задач, который требуют периодического взаимодействия потока с UI нужно использовать [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) или [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).

Comment: Благодарю за отклик, может у Вас есть какой-нибудь пример для анализа ?

Comment: По ссылке на `Task` есть примеры его применения.